# How to know current clicked page on Anko ViewPager

Tags: java, android, anko

I have one viewPager in Anko and I wanna know how to get current page data when I click on view pager item.

```
val mainPager = viewPager {
    id = R.id.image_pager
    backgroundColor = Color.BLACK
    onClick { 
        // need to know current page data from adapter
    }
}.lparams(matchConstraint, context.displayMetrics.widthPixels)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get data from arraylist :-

```
arraylist.get(viewpager.getCurrentItem());
```

Comment: "getCurrentItem()" that's what i actually looking for. Thanks